# Joomla 3.10.11 on server with MySql 8.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql

On my online server which has MySql 5.7 and PHP 7.4 I have three sites in joomla which have the following:

- Mywebsite1 with joomla 3.10.11 and JD Boston template with Helix framework 3.0.3
- Mywebsite2 with joomla 3.10.11 and Masoko2 template with Helix framework 2.0.11
- Mywebsite2 with joomla 4.4.0 and template TZ Alita with Astroid framework 2.6.6

I imported all three sites to my server locally where I installed PHP version 8.1.2 and MariaDB 10.6.16 and I see that my sites even with Joomla version 3.10.11 continue to work.

Since my online server on March 24 will be upgraded from MySql 5.7 to 8.0(LTS) the question is: In your opinion will this MySql change bother my sites with Joomla 3.10.11 or not?